# Using simplehtmldom trying to find a URL with out and id or class

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, simple-html-dom

First time poster on here, did about a couple hours of searching and trying but got stuck... so go easy on me :)

With a page containing this...

`<li onclick="javascript:trackClick(14423, 'web'); document.location='http://www.mywebsite.com';">
    <img class="listing-control" src="img/url-profile-listings.png" alt="Get Directions" width="51" height="51" style="padding:4px;">
    <span id="web14423">Visit Website</span>
</li>`

I am trying to get the url http://www.mywebsite.com in the document.location of the li tag.

The only unique and constant thing to key off is the "Visit Website" text in the span tag.  Is there any way to find that and go up to the parent li tag to the the document.location property from the onclick event?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks,

MrMo.

Comment: on which event do you want to fetch the url i mean on click on li or img ?? post your js code

Answer (score 1):

Of course load it in the `SimpleHTMLDOM` object, then just target the `<li>` tag with it. Target the `onclick=""` attribute to get the values inside it.

<sub>*Disclaimer: I'm not a regex expert in any way.*</sub>

```
$html_string = <<<EOT
<li onclick="javascript:trackClick(14423, 'web'); document.location='http://www.mywebsite.com';">
    <img class="listing-control" src="img/url-profile-listings.png" alt="Get Directions" width="51" height="51" style="padding:4px;">
    <span id="web14423">Visit Website</span>
</li>
EOT;

$html = str_get_html($html_string);

// after loading the html with either str_get_html or file_get_html
foreach($html->find('li') as $list) {
    $script = $list->onclick;
    preg_match('/document.location\s*=\s*\'(.*?)\';/', $script, $match);
    if(!empty($match)) {
        $url = $match[1];
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ghost! preg_match ... that's the stuff!  After posting yesterday I was trying to brute force a solution using strtok but only got so far and I was thinking there must be a more straight forward way... This worked great.  Thanks so much, I am going to dig in to the documentation for [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to learn more (link included if anyone else is interested).